# Django many to many relationship. How to get all rows which primary key doesn't exist on another table?

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I've 3 models A, B and C. they are as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name=models.TextFeild()


class B(models.Model):
    name=models.TextFeild()


class C(models.Model):
    a=models.models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='as')
    b=models.models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bs')
```

I want to get all B's which doesn't exist in C with `A.name = 'jhon'`
I've tried

```
taken_tests = C.objects.filter(a.name='jhon')
queryset = B.objects.filter().exclude(pk__in=taken_tests)
```

But this gives me all B's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `related_name` in `exclude`:

```
B.objects.exclude(bs__a__name='jhon')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)?

So the code will be:

```
a1 = A(name='a1')
a1.save()
a2 = A(name='a2')
a2.save()
b1 = B(name='b1')
b1.save()
b1.a.add(a1)
b2 = B(name='b2')
b2.save()
b3 = B(name='b3')
b3.save()
b3.a.add(a2)
ba = B.objects.filter(a=a1)
bna = B.objects.exclude(a=a1)
```

If you need some attributes on the relationship table you can loot at [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)